Horizontal line splitting $a-a\cos(bx)$ from $0$ to $2\pi/b$ into two equal halves
I was wondering what horizontal line would divide the curve $y=1-\cos x$ from $0$ to $2\pi$ into two halves of equal area and if the result could be generalised for any curve with equation $a-a\cos(bx)$ from $0$ to $\frac{2\pi}b$.
I tried for myself but ended up with equations consisting of inverse trignometric functions which I was unable to simplify and solve.
enter image description here

Write the équations and tell where you are stuck

I edited the question and wrote using MathJax

Yes, you should get an equation
$$ 2 \sqrt{y}\, \sqrt{2-y}-2 (-1+y) \arccos \! \left(-1+y \right) 
 = \pi
$$
that does not appear to have a closed-form solution. Most equations of this type, involving a variable and a transcendental function of the variable, do not.  The numerical solution is approximately $0.67132583709145378318$.
